# scheduling php mysql db design

Tags: php, mysql, database

We are trying to design a program that will allow users to book tutors based on tutors' availability. So we want tutors to tell us when (what time, day, etc) they are available/not available, and when a user books a specific day and time, we only want to show that user the tutors that are available for that particular day and time.

For example, tutors could tell us they are available M-W from 9-5PM.

How could I design such a table?

I was thinking of doing the followin

```
non-availability:
(this allows tutors to tell me they are not available on a specific date ... say 4/15/2012 10PM)
date date 
time_start datetime
time_end datetime

recurring_non-availability
(this allows tutors to tell me that they are not available every Monday from 9-5pm)
dayOfWeek enum
time_start
time_end
```

So basically, tutors can specify for each day of the week, the times they are not available. They can also specify specific dates they are not available. If a user wants a tutor for a specific date like 4/20 10AM, I will first query the non-availability table to make sure there are no conflicts for 4/20 10 AM, and then query the recurring_non_availability table to make sure they are no conflicts for Friday (4/20 is on a Friday) 10 AM.  I am not sure if this design will give me the best picture of a tutor's availability.

Comment: this columns in your sql table are determined by what you think is the necessary information based on what you're trying to do - this is not a coding question.

Comment: @techjunkie.css, I think this is valid question - albeit a bit broad.

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to say when a tutor _is_ available, rather than when one isn't?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps set up a table with all the days of the week tutors will be available and then have the times they are stored within like so?

```
Tutor monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday 

bob     9-5    9-5      9-5       10-3    9-12
```